# How to change color of two class points in python plot?

Tags: python, plot

I want to change the colour of points  when I use ax.plot function

```
groups = error_df.groupby('true_class')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.index, group.reconstruction_error, marker='o', ms=4, linestyle='','g','k',
            label= "fraud" if name == 1 else "normal")
```

According to the code, the plot has two class points "fraud" and "normal".

"fraud" is orange and "normal" is blue.

I want to change the colour of "fraud" to green and  "normal" to red.

How can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should be able to do it just like you did with `label`, i.e., pass

`color="green" if name == 1 else "red"`

as an argument to the `plot` method.